# lsblk doesnt see usb drive

Tags: usb, mount

I have USB pendrive formated to fat32 or ntfs with photos. Windows see brokend pendrive and can't repair it. Ubuntu doesn't 'assign letter' at all. I think there could be broken partition table or HW misstake on memory chip.

Can anyone help me how can I try to repair partition table on Ubuntu?
Here are my attempts to mount disk or identify it anywhere in system.

```
shipper@L340:/dev/disk/by-id$ dmesg
[  873.617244] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  879.903953] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  880.624947] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3267, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  880.624960] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  880.624966] usb 1-3: Product: SM3280AA MEMORY BAR 
[  880.624971] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[  880.628864] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  880.629391] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  881.632790] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SMI      USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  881.633426] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  881.689191] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk


shipper@L340:/dev/disk/by-id$ ls -al
celkem 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 340 pro  9 12:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 pro  9 12:35 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 pro  9 12:32 nvme-eui.1915548002710001001b448b44a4aff2 -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-eui.1915548002710001001b448b44a4aff2-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-eui.1915548002710001001b448b44a4aff2-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-eui.1915548002710001001b448b44a4aff2-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-eui.1915548002710001001b448b44a4aff2-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-eui.1915548002710001001b448b44a4aff2-part5 -> ../../nvme0n1p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-eui.1915548002710001001b448b44a4aff2-part6 -> ../../nvme0n1p6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 pro  9 12:32 nvme-WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW-512G-1101_191554800271 -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW-512G-1101_191554800271-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW-512G-1101_191554800271-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW-512G-1101_191554800271-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW-512G-1101_191554800271-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW-512G-1101_191554800271-part5 -> ../../nvme0n1p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 pro  9 12:32 nvme-WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW-512G-1101_191554800271-part6 -> ../../nvme0n1p6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 pro  9 12:35 usb-SMI_USB_MEMORY_BAR-0:0 -> ../../sda


shipper@L340:/dev/disk/by-id$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 090c:3267 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) SM3280AA MEMORY BAR 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:58a3 A4Tech Co., Ltd. USB Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


root@L340:/dev/disk/by-id# lshw -short -class disk -class volume
H/W path             Device          Class          Description
===============================================================
/0/100/1d/0/0/1      /dev/nvme0n1    disk           512GB NVMe namespace
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/1    /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         50MiB Windows NTFS volum
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/2    /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         276GiB Windows NTFS volu
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/3    /dev/nvme0n1p3  volume         500MiB Windows NTFS volu
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/4    /dev/nvme0n1p4  volume         199GiB Extended partitio
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/4/5  /dev/nvme0n1p5  volume         3906MiB Linux swap volum
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/4/6  /dev/nvme0n1p6  volume         195GiB EXT4 volume
/0/a/0.0.0           /dev/sda        disk           USB MEMORY BAR
/0/a/0.0.0/0         /dev/sda        disk
```

Comment: FAT32 and particularly NTFS should only be corrected with Windows tools. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Ubuntu is not a free tool to fix Windows.

Comment: If it's a thumb-drive; that's not *long-term-storage* media but a cheap consumable, so it's possibly a faulty thumb-drive, and just switching to your a new thumb-drive on which you copy the wanted files from your backups is the usual fix. Thumb-drives aren't a safe/secure storage medium; being a cheap consumable (*with no error checking on them anyway*)

Comment: That could be a broken partition table, which windows can't fix.  You could try imaging the drive and then use testdisk or something to try to recover.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky solve it. **But first, if there are important files, try `testdisk` and `photorec` from https://cgsecurity.org**. I have used `photorec` successfully.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Your outputs show that Ubuntu has no problem with this drive and is correctly assigning "a letter" to it, calling it `/dev/sda`. You can see it in `/dev/disk/by-id`, and in the output of `lsusb` and in the output of `lshw`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. We tried to connect/disconnect pen drive many times at Windows and on 20? try it has connected. Videos are unreadable, some photos broken. But many of then was saved. Thank you for direction to try Windows on this proprietary think. Closed.

Comment: @terdon yes it was about /dev/sda

Comment: So what's the problem? You say that "Ubuntu doesn't 'assign letter' at all" but your output shows that the drive is seen and assigned as `/dev/sda`.